# How to combine .metal and .swift in the same package

Tags: swift, xcode, metal

I created a MacOS command line app that defines and successfully calls a Metal kernel. I'm now trying to move this app's .metal and .swift logic into its own package so that it can used in other projects. I expected I would be able to create a Swift package, add my .metal and .swift logic and build/test it with no issues but this has not been the case.

In Xcode I created a new package (File->New->Package). After the package was created I tried to add a Metal file (right-click on sources -> New File). I opened the macOS tab in the window and tried to find a `.metal` template file but there was no result. I then just tried copy/pasting my .metal file into the sources and that worked but when I went to build I got an error

```
CompileSwiftSources normal x86_64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler  (in target '...' from project '...')
...
swiftc -incremental -module-name ...
...
Command CompileSwiftSources failed with a nonzero exit code
```

**How can I add and build .metal files as part of my Xcode Swift package?** I can't seem to find what I'm missing. I've found examples of packages on GitHub that have a combination of Metal and Swift in them and I managed to get [this one](https://github.com/philipturner/metal-fft) (Metal in `sources/other`) to compile on my computer in Xcode.

Comment: The real answer is going to be using package manager extensible build tools. There's a discussion on swift forums about metal files even. https://forums.swift.org/t/returned-for-revision-se-0303-package-manager-extensible-build-tools/46640/9

Answer (score 1):

Have you updated your Swift package file?

**.metallib** file (Bundle.module) is only available once you have specified your resources in the package manifest.

**Package.swift:**

```
.target(
      name: "TargetName",
      dependencies: [],
      resources: [.process("ThePathToYour/Shader.metal")]
 )
```

Comment: Yes I did. I added the resource to my library target 
`.target(name: "...", dependencies: [], resources: [.process("compute.metal")]),`.
I also cleaned my build folder

Comment: Strange. I created a new package and it seems to work now. Only thing I changed this time was adding the files to my project through Xcode (right click -> add files) instead of just `$ cp ...`ing them over. Does this change the build process somehow?

Comment: It's strange, the solution above worked for me. Maybe it's an Xcode bug?